# Attempting to JIT compile method '(wrapper managed-to-native) System.DateTime:GetTimeMonotonic ()

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have this stack trace from some of our users and I have very little idea on how to track it down since it seems to work fine for most of the users.

Same issue is mentioned here: 
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/15701/jit-executionengineexception-on-llvm-compiled-production-app

Any help would be very appreciated!

Device info: iOS 7.1.2, timezone=-25200, 
21:29:27: : Attempting to JIT compile method '(wrapper managed-to-native) System.DateTime:GetTimeMonotonic ()' while running with --aot-only. See http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations for more information.
 -   at System.Threading.Timer+Scheduler.SchedulerThread () [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Threading.Thread.StartInternal () [0x00000] in :0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a rare race condition, there is a bug fix coming up.

Comment: Thanks, looking forward to the bugfix!